# I am trying to convert the datatable data into json format but i got stuck in this, please let me know how to convert it

Tags: json, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to serialize data table when returning the data table.
Hhere is the code and I want to convert datatable into JSON format but don't know how to resolve it.

```
       public async Task<DataTable> GetFlightSearchList()
            {
                string ConStr = _configuration["Data:Flyraja:DbConnectionString"].ToString();
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
                SqlDataAdapter adap;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adap = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM   FlightSearchResults", con);
                adap.Fill(objDT);
                //return objDT;
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DataTable>(objDT);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your data table into the equivalent dictionary of dictionaries:

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> DatatableToDictionary(DataTable dt, string id)
        {
            var cols = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(c => c.ColumnName != id);
            return dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                     .ToDictionary(r => r[id].ToString(),
                                   r => cols.ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => r[c.ColumnName]));
        }
```

Then call `DatatableToDictionary`:

```
public string Index()
        {
            var dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
            dt.Columns.Add("ID");
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Active");

            dt.LoadDataRow(new[] { "ID1", "John", "True" }, true);
            dt.LoadDataRow(new[] { "ID2", "Bill", "False" }, true);

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DatatableToDictionary(dt, "ID"), Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
        }
```

Don't forget to install `Newtonsoft.Json` Nuget package.

Test Result:

[image]